# How are data breakpoints created?

Tags: c, windows, debugging

I was just wondering how **data breakpoints** (aka watchpoint) are created?

I know common breakpoints are made with some special INT3 instruction on x86.

I suppose you can create *software* watchpoint by scanning the memory regularly.

But from the perspective of writing my own debugger with hardware breakpoints, I can't find anything in the [Windows Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) regarding this (only theses two topics on WinDbg [1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/350dyxd0%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) [2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553451%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). I didn't look yet on Linux.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Modern processors have debug hardware built-in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On an x86 processor, you set up data breakpoints by using the [debug registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_debug_register) on the processor.  Debug registers DR0-DR3 store the addresses to watch.  That's the reason that Visual Studio is limited to four data breakpoints.